# Преобразовать строку разделенную пробелами в ArrayList и вывести его в консоли

Tags: java

Преобразовать строку разделенную пробелами в `ArrayList` и вывести его в консоли.

Выводит почему-то только первый элемент массива. Помогите разобраться, что в коде не так.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = 0;
    String s = "";

    System.out.println("Введите строку");
    s = sc.next();

    ArrayList<String> row = new  ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));

    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(row.get(i));
    }

}
}
```

Скриншот работы моей программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
s = sc.next();
```

на

```
s = sc.nextLine();
```

---

`next` - возвращает то, что стоит до пробела

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, а почему именно nextLine() ?

Comment: @sergeyka next - возвращает то, что стоит до пробела. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22458766/6104996  ..... думал тут у нас на русском есть ответ на эту тему. не смог найти

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @sergeyka тогда нажимайте на галку рядом с ответом и поехали дальше)